# When one should use "spring for android"?

Tags: android, spring, mvvm, android-framework

I came across [spring for android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android), which claims to provide `Spring Framework` that aims to simplify the development of native Android applications.

If anyone has already used or explored this framework, please share your thoughts about the scenarios or situations where this can be beneficial over standard android framework (which is somewhat like *MVVM*).

To sum up, I am looking for additional benefits provided by this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated spring for android and my analysis is :

It Does not provide Inversion of control.  Provide popular spring tools like RestTemplate, Social Integration for Android .
Spring provides parsing framework as well, thought not as efficient as jackson.
more yet to be added, keep your finger crossed.

this means whenever you want a ready made solution for RESTor Social Integration(fb/twitter) along with a parser with normal capability, spring for android might be a right choice for you.

if someone will post more accurate answer, i will surely accept that.